# Laravel PHPUnit GET and POST always returning 404

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

Writing up Unit Tests in a Laravel project and whilst for the most part it has been very straight forward with PHPUnit, the `TestCase` methods of `get` and `post` do not work with my application; always returning a 404.

Currently the test in question passes as I'm just trying to run the following:

```
class HttpTests extends TestCase
{
    /**
    * A basic test example.
    *
    * @return void
    */
    public function testExample()
    {
        print_r($this->get('/')->getContent());
    }
}
```

Which outputs the markup of the 404 page of the application.

I know that the correct url is being queried, as adding...

```
{{ Request::url() }}
```

To `404.blade.php` echos the correct URL that I have defined in my `.env` file as

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
```

Not sure how else to fix it, when using more complex solutions like Dusk I never had issues using the `visit` method but it appears to only occur with the built in HTTP request functions for Laravel's `TestCase` class.